# In JavaScript, Is there a situation in which I need to loop only using "for" and I can't loop using "while" or vice versa?

Tags: javascript

I know that there is a reason to have `while` loop and `do{} while()` loop:

> Using do{} while() you'll iterate at least 1 time, using while(){}
>   you'll iterate only if the condition is true.

But I'm wondering if there is a such **real reason** that JavaScript has implemented the *for* and *while* loop?

```js
var example = ["a", "b", "c"];

for(var i=0; i<example.length ; i++){
 console.log("using for: " + i);
}

var i=0;
while(i<example.length){
 console.log("using while: " + i);
 i++;
}
```

Comment: they aren't the same. they each have their place.

Comment: you better be asking why C (or earlier another language) has it - because thats why JavaScript has it.

Comment: You can use these two things to accomplish the same end result, if you change your code to accommodate using the different loops.  But that doesn't make them the same thing.  You can also ride a bicycle to the same destination to which you ride a skateboard, but that doesn't make a bicycle and a skateboard the same thing.

Comment: Why even have a do-while loop since you can just repeat the body of a regular while loop outside the loop to simulate a do block?

Comment: @danielA.White can you explain how they aren't the same?

Comment: `for` is for enumeration, generally for arrays. while `while` is good for processing looking for a boolean flag.

Comment: I understand that there are not the same thing but my question is **Why JavaScript has "for" and "while" loop?**

Comment: So if you understand that they are not the same thing, why are you still asking?

Comment: @DhekraZELAITI: To provide programmers with ways of repeating a block of code under a variety of conditions.  Loops are good for exactly that.

Comment: because I want to know if there is a case in which I need to loop only using **for** and I can't loop using **while**!

Comment: @DhekraZELAITI: Do you have an example of something where you suspect one loop may be preferable over another?  Have you encountered a problem using one kind of loop which is solved by using another?

Comment: a `for` loop keeps the code clean having the initialization, condition, and step all on 1 line.

Comment: its up to you how you want to write your code and if you are sharing with others that they agree with the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following is just my opinion. No limit of warranty!*

You could say that `for` and `while` are two abstractions for `GOTO`. So, you as a programer have two choices to express a piece of code that should be executed several times.

For the machine it (might) not matter if you write a `for` or a `while`, but for us humans it is nice to have a *visual* distinction. Because at the end of a day a human has to read and understand the code that another human has written. Depending on the use case it might be easier to understand if it is written the one way or the other.

`for` is better when you know the end and the iteration is incremental. `while` on the other hand is better if the iteration should end if a predicate is fulfilled and you do not know when this happens.

If you take a closer look at your code, you'll see that you "implemented" a `for` loop by using an integer als iterator inside the `while`. But it is much easier to read and understand the `for` than the `while`.